# How did William survive the strongest fire attack from Valacirca?

Tags: saihate-no-paladin

Beside fighting skills and enchantments, William isn't someone who can't be hurt. But when the dragon attacked him with his strongest fire attack, it didn't kill him. Why? Was it because of the spirits he got inside him? Was because of the goddesses protecting him? No reason was given in the anime.

How did William survive the strongest fire attack from Valacirca?